# ASP.NET button does not postback to server

Tags: asp.net

In the following html, the btnLogin button is not posting back to the server.
This is a master page , with AutoEventWireup="true"
Any idea?

```
<div id="loginForm" runat="server">                        
    <div id="mostrarLogin" runat="server">
        <div class="headerForm" ><h2>Iniciar Sesión</h2></div>
            <article>
                <div class="ejemplo clear" runat="server" id="loginClear">
                    <label>Casilla de Correo</label>
                    <asp:TextBox name="casilla" runat="server" id="txtCasilla"></asp:TextBox>
                    <label>Contraseña</label>    
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" name="pass" id="txtPass"></asp:TextBox>
                    <p><input name="terminos" type="checkbox" value="acepto" runat="server" id="chkRecordarme" />&nbsp;Recordar contraseña</p>

                     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="left btnRecuperar">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
                     <asp:Button name="enviar" Text="Ingresar" class="leermas-naranja right" runat="server" id="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"/> 

        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

post back page:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //Something    
}
```

Comment: Is there a `form` somewhere?

Comment: Does `Page_Load` event fire?

Comment: What do you mean "post back page:" ? That code should be in the master page code-behind.

Comment: Wiktor: yes, the for is there
Win: yes, Page_Load evet is firing
Mike: sorry, i meant codebehind page

Comment: Update:if i move the button at the root of the form tag the event is fired correctly

Comment: New Update:the div loginForm is showed with fancybox, if i modify the div like this (note `style="display:block"`) `<div id="loginForm" runat="server" style="display:block">` the event is fired as well
So the problem seems to be the fancybox, any idea?

Comment: I found the solution to my problem, it was the fancybox2 plugin that caused the issue, the fix was to add
parent: `"form:first"` and `modal: false` to the jquery call
`//pop up login
$(".loginBtn").fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    parent: "form:first",
    modal: false
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, it was the fancybox2 plugin that caused the issue, the solution was to add two lines:
parent: `"form:first"` and `modal: false` to the jquery call, see code bellow

```
//pop up login 
$(".loginBtn").fancybox({ 
    parent: "form:first", 
    modal: false,
    //original code 
});
```